# How can you pass a multi-line output from one command as n arguments to a single command, not n commands with a single argument?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh, xargs

#### TL;DR

Given the input

```
a
b
c
```

I am trying to execute command `foo` with each input as a separate argument (e.g. 'n' inputs means a single call to `foo` with 'n' arguments)...

```bash
foo a b c
```

I am not trying to execute `foo` once per argument (e.g. 'n' inputs means 'n' calls to `foo` each with a single argument iteration)

```bash
# Not this!
foo a
foo b
foo c
```

Can this be done outside of string concatenation with `eval`?

#### Summary

I'm trying to find the recommended way to pass the multi-line output of one command as individual arguments to a second command. To be clear, I am not trying to execute that second command, once per argument. I'm trying to pass *all* the arguments to a single command instance.

This is easier demonstrated than explained.

Consider this shell command with a hard-coded list of three swift source files (note some have spaces and are in subfolders)...

```bash
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE" "main.swift" "car.swift" "Models/Road Bike.swift"
```

It's pretty straightforward and executes as expected.

But... I'm trying to automate things so I want that list of source files to be the result of a recursive `find` operation.

Here's the `find` command I started with...

```bash
find * -type f -name "*.swift"
```

Executing that yields the following results...

```
Models/Road Bike.swift
car.swift
main.swift
```

#### Attempt 1

As such, for my first attempt, I tried this...

```bash
SOURCE_FILES=$(find * -type f -name "*.swift" | tr '\n' ' ')
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE" $SOURCE_FILES
```

...but it didn't work.  I (incorrectly) thought it was because the filenames weren't properly quoted.

#### Attempt 2

Because of the above I changed it to this to wrap each filename accordingly...

```bash
SOURCE_FILES=$(find * -type f -name "*.swift" | while read fn; do echo \"$fn\"; done | tr '\n' ' ')
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE" $SOURCE_FILES
```

This did properly add the quotes to the filenames, but that's when I realized my earlier error... it's not treating it as separate arguments, one per filename, it's treating it as a single argument with one giant filename with embedded quotes (and last time it was one giant filename without embedded quotes).

#### Attempt 3 - Success!

Ok, that's when I realized I could go brute-force and just build the exact command I wanted as a literal string, then execute it using `eval`. Armed with that knowledge, I finally went with this...

```bash
SOURCE_FILES=$(find * -type f -name "*.swift" | while read file; do echo \"$file\"; done | tr '\n' ' ')
cmd='xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE" '$SOURCE_FILES
eval $cmd
```

...and sure enough it worked.  BUT... I can't help but feel this is workaround after workaround after workaround.

Is there a simpler way to pass the output from the `find` (or `ls`, etc.) command as individual input arguments to the compile (or any other) command?  How else can this be solved?  What's the recommended/preferred way to do this?

*Note: I'm using zsh but if it's also bash-compatible, that would be good too.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying too hard.

```
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to work. This executes the command specified by xargs once per item, not multiple arguments on the same command.  And even when adding `-L 1000` which does put them on the same command, I'm now getting ld: file not found: car.swift. Looks like xargs is also losing the current directory but even if I update the find to return full paths using `find ~+ -type f -name "*.swift"`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe : No. The `-print0` causes the output of `find` to be terminated by a null byte (if you omit the pipe, you won't see individual lines, but just one huge string of all the files), and the `-0` tells xargs to split the input on the null byte. I would howver double check these options using the man-pages, because the default `find` and `xargs` on macos might be different. If in doubt, install the Gnu utilities on your mac.

Comment: Aaah... I think I missed the `-print0` argument in my own code.  Lemme try that again and I'll come back here and mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: Aaah... something else that made things more complicated.  When using this technique, you ***can not*** use the `-I` argument for the placeholder as I was trying to (I wanted the args to be in the middle of my command.)  When you do, it goes back to executing one command per argument, not one command with all arguments.

Comment: The requirement for this to work is that the input to `xargs` must be short enough to fit into a single command invocation. In this case, there is probably no risk that it would not work; but for future visitors, this might be worth mentioning.

Comment: You can skip the -print0 and -0 arguments if you want. I prefer to use them, because any weird file names that contain new lines or other garbage can confuse things. Which is rare but it happens And no, it should execute the command only once with all the arguments. @tripleee yes, but at least on Linux these days, the command line argument length is 2 megabytes, which is close enough to unlimited for any rational use. It will call the command 2 or 3 times if it exceeds that. If the command can't cope with that, you're screwed anyway.

Comment: We are collecting answers for the benefit of future visitors, too. But yes, if you have arguments which are longer than `xargs` can handle in one go, they are also too long to handle without `xargs`, and you are "screwed anyway".

Comment: Why use `xargs` instead of `find`'s own `-exec` primary?

Comment: @chepner find -exec executes once per file, which is both not what the OP asked for, and in general is inefficient if xargs can do the job and execute once altogether

Comment: `-exec ... \;` executes once per file; `-exec ... +` passes as many files as possible to the command.

Answer (score 1):

#### first

Save yourr multi-line output in an array

#### second

Pass the array to a desired command

#### example - test

Run line by line

```bash
# cd into a test directory
cd `mktemp -d`

# generate list of files
touch file-{01..09}.txt

# save the list in an array + remove trailing newlines 
mapfile -t list < <(find -type f -name \*.txt)

# check the output
echo "${list[@]}"

# see the size of the array
echo "${#list[*]}"

# see indexes 
echo "${list[0]}"
echo "${list[1]}"
echo "${list[2]}"

# pass the array to a command you liked 
# for example substitute txt with TXT
sed 's/txt/TXT/g' <<< "${list[*]}"

# output
./file-09.TXT ./file-08.TXT ./file-07.TXT ./file-06.TXT ./file-05.TXT ./file-04.TXT ./file-03.TXT ./file-02.TXT ./file-01.TXT
```

---

Q. Doesn't this still operate on each argument one by one?
A. It is not the **array** responsibility to operate one by one, it is the **command** we use that has what and which behavior.

For example if you pass the array to `echo` it works. Because `echo` accepts N argument, no limitation.
On the other hand if you pass the array to `diff` it does not work, simply because it only accepts two argument

#### echo test

```bash
echo ${list[@]}
./file-09.txt ./file-08.txt ./file-07.txt ./file-06.txt ./file-05.txt ./file-04.txt ./file-03.txt ./file-02.txt ./file-01.txt
```

#### diff test

```bash
diff  ${list[@]}
diff: extra operand './file-07.txt'
diff: Try 'diff --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Doesn't this still operate on each argument one by one?  In other words, it runs your sed command once per argument?  Again, I am trying to feel them all as arguments to a single command.  e.g. not `somecmd a; somecmd b; somecmd c` but rather `somecmd a b c`

Comment: This doesn't pass an array; it passes a single line *formed* from an array. You would have to reparse the output to recover the individual file names (which would be difficult if any of the file names contained a space). The use of `mapfile` also wouldn't work if any of the file names contained a newline.

Comment: @chepner *This doesn't pass an array; it passes a single line* Yes because I used `<<<` but it was an example and use case, the `diff` command illustrates this correctly - it is an array

Answer (score 0):

Although I got Xpusostomos' answer of `find -print0 | xargs -0` to work, it is unintuitive to me and only works if the output is used as arguments at the end of a command (as discussed in the comments), not in the middle.

Here's a more intuitive method that works for me. Using the shell `` ` `` [backtick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands/165637#165637):

```
xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE" `find * -type f -name "*.swift"`
```

The backticks tell your shell to execute the command in the ticks first and then the output replaces the ticked text as if you had typed it. So you could use it to put output wherever you want in your commands, not just at the end of a command. You can also pipe within the ticks which lets you manipulate output more (e.g. sorting), which a `find -exec` alone cannot do.