# How can I filter out files with a shebang from those passed to xargs?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, zsh

#### TL;DR

I'm trying to write a simple script that compiles all `.swift` files in a given folder and any of it's subfolders, but which excludes those files that start with a shebang.

#### The Details

I'm trying to write a simple utility that will let me compile multiple Swift files into a single compiled output without requiring any advanced IDEs or project files, etc.  The folder structure itself will be the project's definition with the root being wherever I find a `main.swift` file.

Assuming I've already found `main.swift` and am in the according directory, starting with the `find` command, I can find all relevant Swift files like so...

```bash
find * -type f -name "*.swift"
```

Thanks to another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891255/168179), by appending `-print0` and feeding that to `xargs -0`, they can all be sent to swift compiler in one fell swoop, like so...

```bash
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

> Note: thanks to the use of `-print0` on the `find` command and `xargs -0` on the other side, all *n* arguments are passed in ***at the same time*** to one execution of `xcrun`, not *n* executions of `xcrun` with one argument each. There is only one compilation and one single output file.

The issue is if any of those Swift files are set up as Swift script files (i.e. those that start with a shebang), the compiler rejects them.  They're also most likely to contain top-level statements, something the compiler also doesn't like unless they are in `main.swift`.

For instance, if this is in the file `someutil`...

```swift
#! /usr/bin/env swift
print("Hello from Swift!")
```

...and you ran `chmod +x someutil`, you could now execute that Swift file like any other shell script so long as it's reachable in the path.

```bash
echo Here we go!
someutil
echo Done!
```

Output

```
Here we go!
Hello from Swift
Done!
```

However, if you send that file to the compiler, it will complain both about the shebang and about the top-level statements not being in `main.swift`.

As such, I'm trying to filter out any of the found files which start with a shebang, using that basically as the identifier of Swift scripts to be excluded.

I've seen a lot of grep tutorials for how to *include* only those files, but can't find any that *exclude* them, especially since the above code also depends on the `-print0` of the find command itself (meaning I can't easily do the filtering elsewhere.)

So is this possible?

#### Update - Verify with ArgChecker util.

Several of the answers here *appear* to be correct, but don't actually process the arguments correctly.  To check this, I recommend creating the following 'argchecker' utility.  Simply create a file with the following contents, run `chmod +x` on it and add it to your path.  Now make whatever solution you think works output to `argchecker` instead of the `xcrun` compiler line.  In a lot of these you will see instead of 'n' arguments, you get a single argument with all the expected ones concatenated together.

**File 'argchecker'**

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash
echo "There are $# arguments:"
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++))
do
    echo " $i: ${!i}"
done
```

Then run this...

```bash
chmod +x argchecker
```

and put it in your path.  Finally, test your script like this with the filtering added wherever.

```bash
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 argchecker
```

Comment: Instead of find, could you start with something like `grep -vrl "#!" * | grep ".swift" ` to list the files? Problem then is how to get this piped into the compiler as it is just giving you a list of filenames. I guess that's the point you make in final paragraph.

Comment: Note that `find ... -exec ... {} +` achieves the same benefit as `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` without the overhead of a separate `xargs` executable. It's only the legacy `-exec ... {} \;` usage that's so needlessly inefficient as to run one process per file found.

Comment: Very cool info, @CharlesDuffy! Thanks! Yeah, `xargs` has been problematic for a few reasons.  Now I just need to figure out how to do the filtering of the files as mentioned.

Comment: @Chris : Wouldn't your _grep_ search all lines of the file? We are only interested in the first line of each file.

Comment: That's true, so maybe there's a question of efficiency - not sure how big those files are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop with output of `find` command and run a `grep` inside:

```bash
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do
   grep -qF '#! /usr/bin/env swift' "$f" || printf '%s\0' "$f"
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.swift" -print0) |
xargs -0 xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

**Details:**

- `find . -type f -name "*.swift" -print0`: finds `*.swift` files and prints them with a NUL terminator
- `< <(...)` is process substitution
- `while IFS= read -rd '' f`: Make while loop read input from NUL terminated data. PS: both `IFS=` and `-d ''` are required
- `|| printf '%s\0' "$f"` prints file names with NUL terminator only when `grep` command fails.
- `| xargs -0 xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"` makes `xcrun` command only once on final output of while loop

Comment: If the `xcrun` command is inside the `do/done pair`, doesn't that run the command once per loop?  Again, the compile command should only be executed once with *all* arguments passed in at the same time, not once per argument.

Comment: ok check my updated answer now

Comment: Ok, this seems to work, but I have no idea how! Haha!  Mind putting a little explainer around your code? For instance, what's `IFS=`, and what's the syntax after the done command (e.g. `done < <(find ...)`?

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe, see [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) explaining reading NUL-delimited files (which `IFS=` is a part of), and [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) describing the bug that using `foo < <(...)` in place of `... | foo` works around.

Comment: _grumbles a little about `find *` in place of `find .` being potentially unreliable if run in a directory where there are files whose names begin with `-`, or where an excessive number of files exist_

Comment: Good point about the `find .`.  Hadn't considered if it started with a '-' as that could definitely throw things off.

Comment: Indeed `find *` was a bad copy-paste from question. I have added explanation in answer.

Comment: **.1**: `grep -q` has to read **whole** files where pattern not exist. You may use `find... -exec file {} +...` instead!. **.2**:  Technicaly, your script will match himself, even if *shebang* does'nt. Your pattern could include some *regex* special chars, for sample a circonflex: `'^#! /usr/bin/env...'

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to make an optimization. I'm assuming like any normal Unix, scripts have executable permissions, in which case you could do

```
find * -name '*.swift' ! -perm -u+x -print0 | xargs -0 xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

This means match any file that does *not* (`!`) have permissions (`-perm -`) of user with execute (`u+x`).

Comment: Voted this up bc it has a cool use of permissions, but I want the test to be the shebang itself as you can have a file with a shebang but that isn't (yet) marked executable.  (Side-note my script actually `chmod +x`s any shebang'd files it finds automatically assuming if there's a shebang, it's to be executed.)

Answer (score 0):

May be with a `grep` command between `find` and `xcrun`:

```bash
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -L '^#! /usr/bin/env swift$' -Z | xargs -0 xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -o "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

`grep` option:

- `-L`: Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from  which no output would normally have been printed
- `-Z`: Output  a  zero  byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file name.

Explanations:

**1st step**

```bash
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0
```

Return all found files separated by NUL character. See them with:

```
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | cat -v
```

Output:

```
ex1.swift^@ex2.swift^@ex3.swift^@
```

`^@` are pretty printed NUL chars

**2nd step**

```bash
... | xargs -0 grep -L '^#! /usr/bin/env swift$' -Z
```

`xargs` who accept separated elements by NUL char (`-0` option), launch `grep` command on each element.
`grep` returns file only (`-l` or `-L` option) who DO NOT contains token (`-L` option) and separate each results by NUL char (`-Z` option).  See them with:

```
find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -L '^#! /usr/bin/env swift$' -Z | cat -v
```

Output:

```
ex1.swift^@ex3.swift^@
```

Warning:

- Check the RE `^#! /usr/bin/env swift$` if exactly as you want;
- If you run on macos with BSD `grep` command, check if `-L` and `-Z` options are same as GNU `grep` under Linux or other systems.

**3rd step**
Same as 2nd step except to execute `xcrun` command

Comment: This seems to dump the matching swift filenames as one large, concatenated argument, not multiple arguments.  You can see this yourself by creating a new bash script called `argchecker` (no extension) and inside put this: `echo "There are $# arguments: "${@:1}`. (Make sure to `chmod +x` it and put it in your path).  Then in your code above change `xcrun ...` to `argchecker` and you'll see it returns one, multi-line argument, not many as you would expect.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe it works for me. When I execute `find * -type f -name "*.swift" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -L '^#! /usr/bin/env swift$' -Z | xargs -0 ../argchecker` with three scripts and two non-script source files, I get, `There are 2 arguments: ./no2.swift ./no1.swift` -- it might be a MacOS-specific thing, maybe, or pilot error? If I change `-L` to `-l` I get the three script files.

Comment: Not sure what to say.  Just copied it again... same thing... `There are 1 arguments: 
  1: Models/Road Bike.swift
Models/main.swift
car.swift`

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe Do a `man grep` and see if it supports the `-Z` or `--null` option and that it uses a null delimiter. I'm betting it doesn't; I think that's a GNU thing and I know MacOS is allergic to GNU. That would explain the problem. Why it doesn't give you an error, I don't know. Maybe it means something else.

Comment: I have added some explanations

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe If that turns out to be the problem, assuming none of your files have spaces in them, remove the `-0` from the second `xargs` and the `-Z` from the `grep` and you should be good. If you have spaces, you can I think use anubhava's solution.

Comment: They definitely may have spaces.  People can name the files whatever they want.